# How can I enter the time at 24:00 in timeFiled

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am booking a stadium at a specific time
And everything is correct
But when I enter the from_hour or to_hour to time(24:00) it prompts an error
the erorr is (Cannot use None as a query value)

```
class OpeningHours(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
pitche = models.ForeignKey(Pitche,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
made_on = models.DateField()
from_hour = models.TimeField()
to_hour = models.TimeField()
timing = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=timing)

def clean(self):
    if self.from_hour == self.to_hour:
        raise ValidationError('Wrong Time')
    if self.made_on < datetime.date.today():
        raise ValidationError('InVaild Date')
    if (
        OpeningHours.objects.exclude(pk=self.pk)
        .filter(
            made_on=self.made_on,
            pitche_id=self.pitche_id,
            to_hour__gt=self.from_hour,
            from_hour__lt=self.to_hour,
        )
        .exists()
    ):
        raise ValidationError(
            f'The booked time ({self.from_hour} to {self.to_hour}) is occupied.'
        )
    return super().clean()
```

Comment: Valid times are 0:00 to 23:59.  24:00 generally is not a valid time.  If you want midnight, use 0:00.

Comment: 24:00 is only valid for an interval, not for a time.

Answer (score 0):

Django's TimeField should have a valid time in the range of "00:00" to "23:59. If you insist on having 24:00. You can insert a conversion logic inside the function for example:

```
    if self.from_hour == time(24, 0):
        self.from_hour = time(0, 0)
    if self.to_hour == time(24, 0):
        self.to_hour = time(23, 59)
```